# SQL Insert with intricate SQL

Tags: sql, insert, subquery, expression

I had tried to use a insert into statement with a intricate sql command.
I got two errors:

> Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions
>   are allowed." and "Incorrect syntax near ')'

The Statement:

```
Insert into 
[TestSystem2].[dbo].[Test_Software_Mandant_Status] ([SW_IDN], [Mandant_IDN],
Software_Status], [UserName], [TimeStamp])
values
(15000, 9999,
  (SELECT [Software_Status] 
  FROM [TestSystem2].[dbo].[Test_Software_Status] 
  WHERE [Software_Status_Kennzeichen] = 'S' and [Software_Status_Text] = 'Test'),
testuser,
SELECT GETDATE())
```

I used a similar structured update command at a other elsewhere, that works. I dont like using variables for this insert, anyone can help me to fix this problem?

Comment: is testuser is a String value here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
Insert into [TestSystem2].[dbo].[Test_Software_Mandant_Status] ([SW_IDN], 
                                                               [Mandant_IDN],
                                                               [Software_Status],
                                                               [UserName],
                                                               [TimeStamp])
SELECT 15000, 
       9999, 
       [Software_Status], 
       testuser, 
       GETDATE()
FROM [TestSystem2].[dbo].[Test_Software_Status] 
WHERE [Software_Status_Kennzeichen] = 'S' 
  and [Software_Status_Text] = 'Test',
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally use a variable, it will make the query look cleaner.

```
DECLARE @SoftwareStatus VARCHAR(100)

SELECT @SoftwareStatus = SELECT TOP 1 [Software_Status] 
  FROM [TestSystem2].[dbo].[Test_Software_Status] 
  WHERE [Software_Status_Kennzeichen] = 'S' and [Software_Status_Text] = 'Test')
```

Then your `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO
[TestSystem2].[dbo].[Test_Software_Mandant_Status] 
([SW_IDN], [Mandant_IDN], Software_Status], [UserName], [TimeStamp])
VALUES
(15000, 9999, @SoftwareStatus, 'testuser', GETDATE())
```

Notice that `GETDATE()` does not need it's own `SELECT`

Comment: @user2511414 - I've added that in ;) - however I've put it in quotes

Comment: Notice that GETDATE() does not need it's own SELECT, that fixed one of the errors, thanks!